# heZookeeper CLI not showing node data

Tags: apache, struct, apache-zookeeper

Basically i have setup a new zookeeper instance - version zookeeper-3.6.0

The zookeeper is started successfully and i am able to connect to the cli.

I am trying to create some sample node like below :

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 3] create /myfirstnode "sample-app"
Created /myfirstnode
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 4] get /myfirstnode
sample-app
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 5]
```

you see in the above code, it does not show the data values or Stat Structure .... it just shows sample-app without any stat structure.

Anyone please help, why it doesn't show data like in the below code :

```
cZxid = 0x7f
ctime = Tue Sep 29 16:15:47 IST 2015
mZxid = 0x7f
mtime = Tue Sep 29 16:15:47 IST 2015
pZxid = 0x7f
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 22
numChildren = 0
```

Comment: anyone who have seen this kind of behaviour? no one? please help if someone knows about this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `stat` command:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 4] stat /myfirstnode
cZxid = 0x2
ctime = Tue Apr 28 05:01:37 CEST 2020
mZxid = 0x2
mtime = Tue Apr 28 05:01:37 CEST 2020
pZxid = 0x2
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 10
numChildren = 0
```

Also `help` command is very useful, it will show you all available commands you can execute from the CLI.